# Show $x \leq y$ iff $y^c \leq x^c$ in a lattice which is a boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra, lattice-orders

> Show $x \leq y$ iff $y^c \leq x^c$ where $x,y$ are elements of a lattice $(B,\leq,\lor, \land)$. $(B,\leq)$ is a partially ordered set, and $\lor$ and $\land$ refer to the l.u.b and g.l.b operations respectively.

I started off with the definition of the complement $^c$, which is:

- $x \land x^c = 0$
- $x \lor x^c = 1$

Then, assuming $x \leq y$, I am trying to show $y^c \leq x^c$ - or equivalently, $x^c \leq y^c$ will result in a contradiction. However, I'm unable to proceed. Could someone please help?

Comment: That is not necessarilly true. Suppose you have a [pentagon $N_5$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice#Characteristic_properties) with another (new) element $y_1$ not comparable with $x,y,z$, and define $x^c=y$, $z^c=y_1$, $y^c=x$ and $y_1^c=z$. Then $z<x$ but $x^c \nleq z^c$.

Comment: @amrsa Could you check my answer and tell me if there's some gap in my understanding? I don't really understand the pentagon example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \leq y$, we know that $x \land y = x$ and $x \lor y = y$. Also, from De-morgan's laws we know that $(x \land y)^c = x^c \lor y^c$ and $(x \lor y)^c = x^c \land y^c$.

To show $y^c \leq x^c$, we see that:

- $y^c \land x^c = (x\lor y)^c = y^c$
- $y^c \lor x^c = (x \land y)^c = x^c$

Similarly, starting with $y^c \leq x^c$, we can show $x \leq y$, which completes the proof.

Comment: Your reasoning is right, provided the de Morgan laws apply. The problem is that that is not always the case. In the example I provided, the de Morgans laws don't hold. I'll give you an answer with that comment in more detail.

Comment: Okay sure, that would be nice! I'm doing a course on Boolean Algebra, and I haven't come across any such lattices so far - where De Morgan's laws don't hold. In fact, the question was related to a section that introduced Boolean algebras as lattices. Nonetheless, it'd be interesting to know when De Morgan's laws don't hold, so I'm awaiting your answer!

Comment: Well, for Boolean algebras, the solution can be as you stated in your answer. But in the question you didn't say the lattice was a Boolean algebra.

Comment: Oh, you're right! I'm not sure I completely understand the difference then. I thought every lattice, i.e. a partially ordered set with l.u.b and g.l.b operations is a boolean algebra? Please help me understand the difference, I haven't formally learnt about lattices yet.

Comment: Ok, so I'm having trouble now with my tex installation and in order to give you an answer as I wanted I'd need to draw the lattice Hasse diagram. I can't do it now, so I'm not giving you that answer after all, sorry. If you don't get one meanwhile, I might do it later.

Comment: Alright, no problem!

Comment: Of course your answer is correct now, with the extra hypothesis (+1).

Answer (score 3):

What I meant in my comment (before you added that the lattice is a Boolean algebra) is that, for example, with the lattice in the following picture below (where $x'$ is what you denote as $x^c$)

[image]

we have $a < b$ but $b^c = d \nleq c = a^c$.
Likewise, $c^c < d^c$ but $d \nleq c$.
So neither of the implications in the equivalence apply.

Of course this is not a Boolean algebra (neither it is a distributive or even modular lattice), and also the de Morgan laws don't apply, since for example,
$$(a \wedge b)^c = a^c = c \neq 1 = c \vee d = a^c \vee b^c.$$